# Refreshing my fragment not working like I thought it should

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this nice method in my ListFragment I call to fill out the details of my other fragment:

```
private void showClientDetails(int pos) {           
        myCursor.moveToPosition(pos);
        int clientId = myCursor.getInt(0);         
        if(mIsTablet) {

                // Set the list item as checked
                getListView().setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex, true);

                // Get the fragment instance
                ClientDetails details = (ClientDetails) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.client_details);
                // Is the current visible recipe the same as the clicked? If so, there is no need to update

                if (details == null || details.getClientIndex() != mCurrentSelectedItemIndex) {
                        // Make new fragment instance to show the recipe
                        details = ClientDetails.newInstance(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex, clientId, mIsTablet);
                        // Replace the old fragment with the new one
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.client_details, details);
                        // Use a fade animation. This makes it clear that this is not a new "layer"
                        // above the current, but a replacement
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        ft.commit();
                }
        }
}
```

It is called when the user clicks on a client in the ListFragment view:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       mCurrentSelectedItemIndex = position;    
           showClientDetails(position);
}
```

This works great, but then another FragmentActivity can change the data that this displays so I thought this would work:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);          
            //update the client list incase a new one is added or the name changes
    if(requestCode==1899)
    {               
      myCursor.requery();
      theClients.notifyDataSetChanged();
          showClientDetails(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex); //now if client was edited update their details in the details fragment
    }
}
```

Now I know the line:

`if (details == null || details.getClientIndex() != mCurrentSelectedItemIndex) {`

Prevents the block of code being reached when its called in my onActivityResult.  So if I remove that `if` statement, then things freak out and the ft.commit() has a hissy fit and gives me the error:

`07-08 16:53:31.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2048): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

So I guess what I am trying to do isn't as cut and dry as it sounds, it makes no sense to me since I can do that onListItemClicked all day and the fragment displays the details of the newly clicked client constantly very well...

I even tried this in my `onActivityResult`:

```
//simulate a click event really fast to refresh the client details
showClientDetails(0);
showClientDetails(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex);
```

that does nothing, is it im trying to call something from the onActivityResult which isn't a Ui thread or what not?

I do have this in my code of the ListFragment as well

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putInt("currentListIndex", mCurrentSelectedItemIndex);
}
```

Is this what the error is complaining about?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The other `FragmentActivity`'s action is performing a task which requires the `Fragment` to save its state via a call to `onSaveInstanceState` in preparation for a new instance being reconstructed. I've seen this for example when I was firing off an activity from a fragment which filled the entire screen as this resulted in the view being detached from the fragment, state needing to be saved etc.

You basically cannot call `commit` between `onSaveInstanceState` and the new instance of the fragment being recreated. See [commit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()).

As for the solution, then either re-think to try and avoid the `commit` being called when it is or alternatively call `commitAllowingStateLoss` if you think it's OK for the UI to change unexpectedly on the user.

Comment: thanks for the response.  The displayed client is updated from the edit clients window so I think that is not unexpected and I think the commitAllowingStateLoss is okay.

Comment: I've used commitAllowingStateLoss, But displayed the alert dialog while orientation changes causes.

Answer (score 19):

I think the answer is to not do any fragment transactions in the onActivityResult. I believe what happens is that when the onActivityResult is called the activity it is in hasn't yet resumed and restarted its fragments.
Use a handler to post back the function call to the activity.

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showClientDetails(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wondering would this work though if your app is in the background, and remains in the background, when onActivityResult is called?

Answer (score 0):

you can do an other thing which no very good but it works.

- finish (you activity)
- do an intent of that same class by :

> Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YouClass.class);
>
> startActivity(mIntent);