# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState with DialogFragment

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-dialogfragment, android-support-library

I am facing issue with DialogFragment / getSupportFragmentManager / Android version 4.x

```
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1314)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1325)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:127)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at com.v1.mypck.TermsAndConditions.showDialog(TermsAndConditions.java:256)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at com.v1.mypck.TermsAndConditions.handleMessage(TermsAndConditions.java:62)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at com.v1.mypck.TermsAndConditions$IncomingHandler.handleMessage(TermsAndConditions.java:53)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-10 19:46:48.228: E/AndroidRuntime(9879):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In below code when i press back it tries to finish current activity and go back to previous activity it throws above error.

Code works well on older version (prior to 4.x).

Can somebody guide me in right direction.

```
public class TermsAndConditions extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<JSONObject>{
    static final String TAG = "TermsAndConditions";
    private static int titleResource;
    private static int messageResource;

    private IncomingHandler handler = null;
    private static final int SHOW_NETWORK_DIALOG = 3;

    static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<TermsAndConditions> mTarget; 

        IncomingHandler(TermsAndConditions target) {
            mTarget = new WeakReference<TermsAndConditions>(target);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TermsAndConditions target = mTarget.get();
            if (target != null) {
                target.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what)  {
            case SHOW_NETWORK_DIALOG:
                titleResource = R.string.msg_alert_no_network_title;
                messageResource = R.string.msg_alert_no_network_message;
                showDialog();
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    private void loadViewData() {
        //Logic to load content.
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<JSONObject> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        if (handler == null){
            handler = new IncomingHandler(TermsAndConditions.this);
        }
        return new JsonLoader(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<JSONObject> arg0, JSONObject jsonData) {
        if(jsonDataObject==null || jsonDataObject.length()==0) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_NETWORK_DIALOG);
        } else {
            loadViewData();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<JSONObject> arg0) {
        if(jsonDataObject==null || jsonDataObject.length()==0) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_NETWORK_DIALOG);
        } else {
            loadViewData();
        }
    }

    public static class JsonLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<JSONObject> {
        public JsonLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            if (jsonDataObject != null) {
                deliverResult(jsonDataObject);
            }
            if (takeContentChanged() || jsonDataObject == null) {
                forceLoad();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public JSONObject loadInBackground() {
            try {
                return response.getJSONObject("result");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override 
        public void deliverResult(JSONObject newJsonData) {
            if (isReset()) {
                if (jsonDataObject != null) {
                    onReleaseResources(jsonDataObject);
                }
            }
            JSONObject oldData = jsonDataObject;
            jsonDataObject = newJsonData;
            if (isStarted()) {
                super.deliverResult(jsonDataObject);
            }
            if (oldData != null) {
                onReleaseResources(oldData);
            }
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onStopLoading() {
            cancelLoad();
        }

        @Override public void onCanceled(JSONObject jsonData) {
            super.onCanceled(jsonData);
            onReleaseResources(jsonData);
        }

        @Override protected void onReset() {
            super.onReset();
            onStopLoading();
            if (jsonDataObject != null) {
                onReleaseResources(jsonDataObject);
                jsonDataObject = null;
            }
        }

        protected void onReleaseResources(JSONObject jsonData) {
            jsonData = null;
        }
    }
    public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
            MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("title", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(messageResource)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .create();
        }
    }
    public void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(titleResource);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)

Answer (score 53):

Here is the answer in another thread:

[Actions in onActivityResult and "Error Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105064/actions-in-onactivityresult-and-error-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsavei)

also here:

[Refreshing my fragment not working like I thought it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628215/refreshing-my-fragment-not-working-like-i-thought-it-should)

This is an example solving this problem:

```
DialogFragment loadingDialog = createDialog();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(loadingDialog, "loading");
                    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue - when using .commitAllowingStateLoss() there is no error but dialog is not shown at all. Isn't there another way how to fix this?

Comment: I am having this exact issue as well, and this does not solve it. In fact, this solution results in a force close immediately, before the DialogFragment is even shown.

Comment: Have you tried calling `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`. I call it after `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();`

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue and I changed the code as bellow

```
newFragment.show(transactionFragment, "dialog");
```

to:

```
transactionFragment.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

the completed code works well for me as bellow, hope that help

```
FragmentTransaction transactionFragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    DialogPageListFragment newFragment = new DialogPageListFragment();
    transactionFragment.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    newFragment.setArguments(extras);
    transactionFragment.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Without calling "show" at all? Doesn't it ruin the way the internal code of DialogFragment works?

Comment: doing like that, getDialog() returns null, inside dialog fragment. :(

Answer (score 5):

Probably, the handler that is responding to the HandleMessage is associated to a destroyed activity.

i.e.: If you rotate the screen, the old destroyed activity will handle the message, then you will call showDialog, and the exception will be thrown:

You are creating a dialog after the old destroyed activity has called his onSaveInstanceState.

Try replacing the callback, with the new created activity, to make sure that you are creating the dialog always in the alive activity.

---

If you are not rotating, put a flag on onSaveInstance like "saving", and disabling it on onRestoreInstance. In your handleMessage method, if the flag "saving" is on, don't show the dialog, just turn on another flag indicating that the dialog must be created on onResume. Then on onResume method, check if in middle of that process, you should create the dialog, if yes, show it on onResume method.

Comment: My activity is only in one orientation.

Comment: Try the second paragraph, put a flag to know when you Activity is saving its instance, and show the dialog inside onResume method (It runs after onRestoreInstanceState)

Comment: After all the trial and errors only solution that worked for me overriding the show method in extended dialog fragment class.

    `code` 
    @Override
     public void show(FragmentManager fm, String tag) {
      try {
       super.show(fm, tag);
      } catch (Throwable e) {
       //Utils.Log(TAG, e.getMessage());
      }
     }

Answer (score 4):

```
fragmentView.post(() -> {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    YourDialog yourDialog = YourDialog.newInstance();
    yourDialog.show(ft, "text_data");
});
```

The goal of post() method in this case is to wait while onResume() of Activity or Fragment will finished.
It works if you want to show DialogFragment from Fragment., f.e. when you want to show your dialog after a system dialog dismissed.

Comment: My code is wrapped in `getView().post()`, but I still see crashes in Crashlytics.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue when post delaying Runnables handler.postDelayed(Runnable runnable, long delayed).

I have solved the problem this way:

1. In onSaveInstanceState I cancel the delayed tasks
2. In onRestoreInstanceState I recreate the task if there have been delayed tasks when activity was destroyed

Comment: Sounds as a nice trick, but how long must be delay in handler.postDelay() ? 100ms is enough

Comment: could you paste some sample code how do you recreate tasks?

Answer (score 1):

too late answer but may be the correct answer.
I made a parent class and and dialog fragment extends from it

```
 public class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    try {
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag).addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d("ABSDIALOGFRAG", "Exception", e);
    }
}

boolean mIsStateAlreadySaved = false;
boolean mPendingShowDialog = false;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    onResumeFragments();
    super.onResume();
}

public void onResumeFragments(){
    mIsStateAlreadySaved = false;
    if(mPendingShowDialog){
        mPendingShowDialog = false;
        showSnoozeDialog();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mIsStateAlreadySaved = true;
}

private void showSnoozeDialog() {
    if(mIsStateAlreadySaved){
        mPendingShowDialog = true;
    }else{
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        BaseDialogFragment snoozeDialog = new BaseDialogFragment();
        snoozeDialog.show(fm, "BaseDialogFragment");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Good answer, keep up.

Answer (score 0):

**onPostResume()**
use post resume method to do your work..
I think you are calling show dialog method in onRestart or onResume, so avoid it and use **onPostResume()** to show your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the current activity isActive() and only in that case start the fragment transaction of DialogFragment. I had a similar problem and this check solved my case.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
CheckinSuccessDialog dialog = new CheckinSuccessDialog();
//dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(dialog, null);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

But but still bad, because got error “Activity has been destroyed”

```
 ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

So my solution is add check `if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed())`

```
CheckinSuccessDialog fragment = CheckinSuccessDialog.newInstance();

  if (fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
                DialogFragment dialog = (DialogFragment) fragment;
                if (!dialog.isAdded()) {
                    fragmentTransaction.add(dialog, 
                          CheckinSuccessDialog.class.getName());
                    if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                }
```

on dismiss:

```
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CheckinSuccessDialog.class.getName());
            if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
                DialogFragment dialog = (DialogFragment) fragment;
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed()) {
                    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the **Activity**, before showing the **dialog** you can do something like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

This worked for me.