# GoogleApiAvailability crash my app when SupportErrorDialogFragment has to show up

Tags: android, google-play-services

My play service which i used in my project is:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
```

i have never called to `GoogleApiAvailability` by my own but i guess when i use gcm or google sign in and it seems that my app crashing becuase that availability checking.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
       at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:139)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment.show(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpn$zza.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

its look that when there are some issues with the play-services and it should show any dialog to the user but my application already not in foreground so the `onSaveInstanceState` already happen and some callback which show error dialog rasie `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Register callbacks in onStart. Unregister callbacks in onStop. Call to super in lifecycle methods. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

The [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) error means that your method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time/state for your requested operation.

Here is the [complete explanation](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) on why you get this kind of error.

> You can try to follow the solution in this
>   [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23096) by
>   overriding the `onResumeFragments()` instead of `OnPostResume`.
>
> - Override `OnPostResume`, if you extend Activity (for API 11+)
> - Override `onResumeFragments`, if you extend FragmentActivity.
>
> For more information, check these related threads.
>
> - [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState with
>     DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262312/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc)
> - [Bug: "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" when showing a DialogFragment inside
>     OnClickListener](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207269)